# Real time website information/content updating

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Since a year and a half I am trying to figure out how some websites update their content in real time without AJAX method.

Please see this example website: https://pro.btcturk.com/en/basic/exchange/BTC_TRY

That website is changing many texts within content in different timing.
It means that when the server is updated with new values in the database then the website is listening to database changes and then reflecting/delivering inside content without ajax calls.

Can someone give an example how to achieve such functionality possibly using Javascript or PHP normal hand-code appreciated?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: The site to which you linked is using `websockets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the process here:

[image]

More information here: [Websockets](https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket)

Comment: I always heard about Websockets but I never new that was used for this.
Thank you for lighting things up, appreciate your help.
Because of your answer I could find that Server-Sent Events is also one solution.